# Gradle build error after adding appium dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, appium

I wish to use appium for automation testing (I'm using Android Studio for dev).
I added a gradle dependency for appium.
However, I am unable to run the app due to following warnings and non zero exit errors.

```
Warning:Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.4.1 is ignored for debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
         In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages
```

And error as:

```
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Source
> D:\Learning\GDLearning\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\websocket-client-9.2.11.v20150529-344b13c53e6f4871f43101e675dc9239cd9ab46b.jar
> and destination
> D:\Learning\GDLearning\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\debug\websocket-client-9.2.11.v20150529-344b13c53e6f4871f43101e675dc9239cd9ab46b.jar
> must be different
```

My **build.gradle** file is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.gdlearning"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-tasks:v1-rev41-1.20.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
    }
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile 'io.appium:java-client:3.2.0'
}
```

Any suggestion/ help would be great!
I explored on SO , tried a few things but it didnt worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to push appium dependencies to your app Build.gradle files.
All you need to do is follow the instructions at official page.

http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#quick-start

Maybe you should:

```
1) Download Appium
2) Setting Evironment variables (ANDROID_HOME, JAVA_HOME, ..)
3) Play with the Appium 
4) Write some test code
```

Comment: So that means I cannot use Android Studio for that? I will be needed  to switch to eclispse or intelli J for that??

Comment: NO. You should use Android Studio to create an APK file.
Then you use Appium to write tests for that APK file.

Comment: where do I write those test cases? and how to run those tests??

Comment: hm, pls refer the instructions first. And then ask for help when you don't know how to do.